# Detect touch that originated from superview

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I'm creating a subclass of UIView to use in a project, and will handle touches on the main view.  I'd like so that when the touch (on the main view) is dragged and contacts the special UIViews, they change their background color. Using UIView's default "touchesMoved" function only detects touches that originate on the specific view.  I could set up the main view to check each instance of the custom UIView, but that would be contrary to encapsulation and lead to messy code.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what your after, but if I put the following code in my view controller, whose view has several RDView views in it, the color of those views will change color when I drag from the main view into the RDView.

```
    override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        var touched = self.view.hitTest((touches.anyObject() as UITouch).locationInView(self.view), withEvent: event)
        if touched is RDView {
            touched?.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        }
    }
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you!  I wasn't aware of the hitTest method.  Now all I'm going to do is from the if statement call a method of the custom view.